# angular 4 not able to push on an array of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to push on an array for every interval but for some reason I get an error either it is `ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'NaN' of undefined` if I use `this.numbers[this.value] = this.value;` or it is `core.es5.js:1020 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` if I use `this.numbers.push(this.value);`

here is my code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game-control',
  templateUrl: './game-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game-control.component.css']
})
export class GameControlComponent implements OnInit {
  timer = null;
  value: number;
  interval: number;
  numbers = [];


  constructor() { }


  ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.numbers);
  }

  onClickStart() {
    console.log('timer called');
    if (this.timer !== null) {
      return;
    }
    this.timer = setInterval(function() {
      this.value += 1;
      // console.log(this.numbers[this.value - 1 ]);
      // this.numbers[this.value] = this.value;
      this.numbers.push(this.value);
      console.log(this.numbers);
    }, this.interval );
  }

  onClickStop() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
    this.timer = null;
  }

}
```

My html is

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 "> 
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onClickStart()">Start</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onClickStop()">Stop</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Clear</button>
          </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10">

  <hr>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <a 
      class="list-group-item" 
      style="cursor: pointer"
      *ngFor="let number of numbers"
      >
      <app-even [num]="number" ></app-even>
      <app-odd [num]="number" ></app-odd> 
    </a>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

but I don't think it matters yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`function () {}` causes `this` not to point to the current class instance anymore, as most coming from other languages would expect, use arrow functions instead to get the desired behavior:

```
this.timer = setInterval(() => {
```

Comment: I'll mark as correct in a few minutes any resource I can read on this problem getting different prob now but solved my original thanks!

Comment: i may be wrong, but if answer is correct, the explanation is semantically wrong. Actually `setInterval` always run its argument from global scope, it is him who breaks `this` with `function()`. This will work with arrow function because it has no proper `this`, always retreiving it from context

Comment: some further reading can be found there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method

Comment: @Kaddath no idea why you think it is semantically wrong. It's the same as `function() { ... }.bind(this)`. It just ensures, that `this` inside the function points to the class instance where the method is defined.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer from this point of view yes, but your sentence can be understood in other ways, just wanted to be clear (semantically unclear would have been better)

Comment: @Kaddath I guess I see now what you mean. I updated my answer.